# BlackBerry - Get Location from GPS, webservice or cell tower

Tags: blackberry, location, coordinates

I am attempting to get location in BlackBerry. I am able to acquire the location successfully through GPS or Google Web service. If GPS is unavailable (inside a building) or not supported in the handset, location is acquired through Google Web service. However I would like to update this class to do the following:

1) Check if GPS is available -> Get Location from GPS 
2) Else Check if internet is available -> (Yes) Get Location from Google Webservice 
3) (No) Get Location from mobile network cell tower
4) Update the location continuously after a given interval (10-20 seconds)

Kindly help.

```
public class GPSHandler { 

       private GPSThread _gpsThread;
       private Coordinates _location;
       private boolean _gotLocation;
       private GPSListener _listener;

       /** this class will be a Singleton, as the device only has one GPS system */
       private static GPSHandler _instance;

       /** @return the Singleton instance of the GPSHandler */
       public static GPSHandler getInstance() {
          if (_instance == null) {
             _instance = new GPSHandler();
          }
          return _instance;
       }

       /** not publicly accessible ... use getInstance() */
       private GPSHandler() { 
          _gpsThread = new GPSThread();
          // NOTE: you might not want to call start() unless you have a listener.
          //  Otherwise, just make sure to handle the case where the location is
          //  received before setListener() is called.
          _gpsThread.start(); 
       }

       public void setListener(GPSListener listener) {
          // only supports one listener this way
          _listener = listener;   
       }

       private void setLocation(final Coordinates value) {
          _location = value;
          if (value.getLatitude() != 0.0 || value.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
             _gotLocation = true;
             if (_listener != null) {
                // this assumes listeners are UI listeners, and want callbacks on the UI thread:
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                      _listener.onLocationReceived(value);
                   }
                });
             }
          }
       }

       private class GPSThread extends Thread {

          private void getLocationFromGoogle() {
             try { 
                int cellID = GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getCellId(); 
                int lac = GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getLAC(); 

                String urlString2 = "http://www.google.com/glm/mmap"; 

                // Open a connection to Google Maps API  
                ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory(); 
                ConnectionDescriptor connDesc; 
                connDesc = connFact.getConnection(urlString2); 

                HttpConnection httpConn2; 
                httpConn2 = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection(); 
                httpConn2.setRequestMethod("POST"); 

                // Write some custom data to Google Maps API  
                OutputStream outputStream2 = httpConn2.openOutputStream();//getOutputStream(); 
                writeDataGoogleMaps(outputStream2, cellID, lac); 

                // Get the response   
                InputStream inputStream2 = httpConn2.openInputStream();//getInputStream(); 
                DataInputStream dataInputStream2 = new DataInputStream(inputStream2); 

                // Interpret the response obtained  
                dataInputStream2.readShort(); 
                dataInputStream2.readByte(); 

                final int code = dataInputStream2.readInt(); 
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                      Dialog.alert(code + "");   
                   }
                });                        

                if (code == 0) { 
                   final double latitude = dataInputStream2.readInt() / 1000000D; 
                   final double longitude = dataInputStream2.readInt() / 1000000D; 
                   setLocation(new Coordinates(latitude, longitude, 0.0f));

                   UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                         Dialog.alert(latitude+"-----"+longitude);   
                      }
                   });

                   dataInputStream2.readInt(); 
                   dataInputStream2.readInt(); 
                   dataInputStream2.readUTF(); 
                } else { 
                   System.out.println("Error obtaining Cell Id "); 
                } 
                outputStream2.close(); 
                inputStream2.close(); 
             } catch (Exception e) { 
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage()); 
             } 
          }

          private void tryGetLocationFromDevice() {
             _gotLocation = false;
             try {
                Criteria myCriteria = new Criteria(); 
                myCriteria.setCostAllowed(false); 
                LocationProvider myLocationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(myCriteria); 

                try { 
                   Location myLocation = myLocationProvider.getLocation(300); 
                   setLocation(myLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates()); 
                } catch ( InterruptedException iex ) { 
                   System.out.println(iex.getMessage());
                } catch ( LocationException lex ) { 
                   System.out.println(lex.getMessage());
                } 
             } catch ( LocationException lex ) { 
                System.out.println(lex.getMessage());
             }

             if (!_gotLocation) { 
                getLocationFromGoogle();
             } 
          }

          public void run() { 
             int bbMapsHandle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("net_rim_bb_lbs");    // OS 4.5 - 6.0
             int bbMapsHandle60 = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("net_rim_bb_maps"); // OS 6.0
             if (bbMapsHandle > 0 || bbMapsHandle60 > 0) { 
                tryGetLocationFromDevice();
             } else {
                getLocationFromGoogle();
             }
             return; 
          } 
       } 

       private void writeDataGoogleMaps(OutputStream out, int cellID, int lac) throws IOException { 
          DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(out); 
          dataOutputStream.writeShort(21); 
          dataOutputStream.writeLong(0); 
          dataOutputStream.writeUTF("en"); 
          dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Android"); 
          dataOutputStream.writeUTF("1.0"); 
          dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Web"); 
          dataOutputStream.writeByte(27); 
          dataOutputStream.writeInt(0); 
          dataOutputStream.writeInt(0); 
          dataOutputStream.writeInt(3); 
          dataOutputStream.writeUTF(""); 

          dataOutputStream.writeInt(cellID); 
          dataOutputStream.writeInt(lac); 

          dataOutputStream.writeInt(0); 
          dataOutputStream.writeInt(0); 
          dataOutputStream.writeInt(0); 
          dataOutputStream.writeInt(0); 
          dataOutputStream.flush(); 
       } 

    }
```

Comment: It's not possible to get location from tower without internet. You could get cell id but you need fetch coordinates from online databases after

Comment: @Eugen, so it is not possible to get coordinates through cell tower triangulation? I believe that is a lacking in BlackBerry. Can you provide me with the source documents that states the way of acquiring location in BlackBerry as well as its limitations?Thanks

Comment: What about refreshing the location automatically without clicking the button. Auto refresh the location from GPS/Google Webservice.

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/GPS-Location-through-cell-tower-triangulation/td-p/104539

Comment: For auto refresh you could set LocationListener or run own thread/timer and take periodically new coordinates. Your option is thread/timer since you want to use different sources

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong about cell tower triangulation. Please review this: https://developer.blackberry.com/services/locate

Comment: @Sarah For web-service: try this WEB-SERVCE:http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=21.05487,35.01254&sensor=true

Comment: @alishaik786, thanks but in my class I am successfully able to get the location from GPS and Google Web service (which ever is available). My concern is to get the location from Cell Tower and include this option in my existing class (above), that is, check if GPS avaialble (priority) else check if internet available use Google webservice else use Cell Tower triangulation.

Comment: To use CELLSITE_PROVIDER you'll need to have phone coverage (not sure if full internet connectivity is needed). You also have Wi-Fi geolocation available from OS 6.0 onwards. Just use `BlackBerryCriteria` and `BlackberryLocationProvider`, these are much easier to use.